# Tarski-Vaught test clarification

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have a statement of the Tarski-Vaught test as follows.

---

Let $\mathscr{M}$ be an $\mathscr{L}$-structure and let A $\subseteq |\mathscr{M}|$. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) A is the universe of an elementary substructure of $\mathscr{M}$. Since on each subset of $\mathscr{M}$ there can only live at most one substructure of $\mathscr{M}$, this property is referred to as "A is a substructure of $\mathscr{M}$".

(ii) For every $\mathscr{L}$-formula $\phi(x, \bar{y})$ and all $\bar{a} \in A^{\bar{y}}$, if $\mathscr{M} \vDash \exists x \phi(x, \bar{a})$, then there is some $b \in A$ with $\mathscr{M} \vDash \phi(b, \bar{a})$.

---

I'm unsure about part (i) - why is it that on each subset of $\mathscr{M}$ there can only live at most one substructure of $\mathscr{M}$?

Answer (score 3):

That's by definition of a substructure. Given a subset $A$ which contains all constant terms, you can make it into an $L$-structure by restricting all functions and relations from $M$ to $A$ (i.e. by removing all tuples which have elements not in $A$).

This $L$-structure is considered a substructure if your functions didn't lose any elements. I.e. if $f$ is an $n$-ary function and $M\vDash f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\doteq b$ for $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in A$ then $b \in A$.

If the former holds then $A$ is a substructure (with the particular interpretation for the symbols of $L$ described above), and else it is not.

Now Vaught test gives you a criterion to decide whether $A$ (considered as the structure described above) is also elementary, i.e. whether the theories of $A$ and $M$ coincide.

Comment: There are some typos in your second paragraph. You actually do not need to refer to $M$ there anywhere, you can just say "if $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ then $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in A$".

Comment: I disagree, to the least you need to say that $f^M(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in A$, which is in the same vein.

Comment: Ho! He's alive!

Comment: Better than ever. Come to Jlem so we can get drunk.

Comment: @ShaiDeshe Sure, it might be clearer to make explicit that we are talking about the interpretation of $f$ in $M$. I would still write $f^M(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in A$ or $b \in A$ (given how it is stated now), rather than $f \in A$.

Comment: Oh I see now, yes, the $f\in A$ part was a complete typo (fixed). I still think that writing $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in A$ is misleading, though.